# How to expand my primary partition?

Tags: ubuntu, disk

I am running out of space on my primary NVME drive that holds my Ubuntu install. Using the Ubuntu Disks application, I cannot resize the partition, despite there being 95GB of free space on the drive. What is the quickest way to expand my primary partition, without any data loss?

From my research, it seems I would have to make an image with Clonezilla, reformat the drive entirely (with GParted?), and then restore the image. Is this the best way to do this? Or is there a far easier or quicker method?

Here is a picture of my disk layout:

[image: Disk Layout]

Comment: It's likely you can't resize it because your system is currently running off of it, but you should be able to by using GParted on a live USB/ISO, and using the resize/move option. As always, make sure you have a backup of everything beforehand.

Comment: Great, that's what I was guessing the problem was. thank you! Is Clonezilla the best way to make a backup?

Comment: You are using older MBR partitioning with 4 primary partition limit. You can use newer gpt partitioning even if BIOS booting but then need a bios_grub partition. If newer UEFI system you need an ESP - efi system partition for UEFI system files. I started converting drives to gpt back in 2010 on old BIOS only system. Then added ESP on new drives starting in 2012, but did not have an UEFI system until several years later. First two partitions on every drive & larger flash drive are an ESP & bios_grub.

Comment: @oldfred has a point, however be careful as it might make your drive unbootable (likely fixable, but not necessarily without hassle). With regards to backups I can't comment on specific utilities much, however if you can create a byte-perfect copy of the disk which you can later restore if necessary that could be useful (in case, for example, you change your mind). I'll use my prior comment as an answer then, as it seems it was the partition being mounted and used was preventing it from being resized.

Comment: With MBR->GPT conversion, more information can be found online, for example https://askubuntu.com/a/85857

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you can't resize it because your system is currently running off of it, but you should be able to by using GParted on a live USB/ISO, and using the resize/move option. As always, make sure you have a backup of everything beforehand.